# Partial word search in with tsvector type column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, full-text-search, sql-like

I have added a table column `document` of `tsvector` type:

```
ALTER TABLE Schema.Table
ADD COLUMN document tsvector;

update Schema.Table
SET document = to_tsvector(Table::text);
```

`LIKE` does not work with `tsvector` type columns to search for a partial match. I would like to find 'Missing', 'Miss', 'Missplaced' etc. with a query like this (pseudo code, not working):

```
SELECT * FROM Schema.Table WHERE document ILIKE 'Miss%';
```

How can I search for a partial word in `tsvector` type column?

Comment: You could start with the manual, that shows you how to use full text search: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) allows **prefix matching** - with index support:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE document @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'Miss:*');
```

Note `:*` appended to the (leading!) search word.
See:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157982/3684)

Comment: Hey, @Erwin, Your help was most useful for me. I came across one issue where to_tsvector("POC1_Table"::text) does not work with NULL values. (ts_vector is not created is any NULL is there in that row). Then, I used document = to_tsvector(coalesce(CAST (COL1 as text),'') || ' ' || coalesce( COL2 ,'')). Here COL1 is integer so need coalesce CAST and where COL2 is text. This will work even any value is NULL. Do you know any better way to convert integer, bigint, binary values in ts_vector?

Comment: @Mehul: Just `concat_ws(' ', col1, col2)`. You don't even need an explicit cast for this as `concat_ws()` coerces automatically. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556331/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860