# How to reference the column alias of a concatenation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I'm trying to select a concatenation as an alias then reference that alias in a `WHERE` clause, but I can't get it working. Here's an example:

```
select concat(area_code, "-", phone_triad, "-", phone_quad) as phone_number, first_name, last_name
from info_table 
where phone_number in (<LIST OF NUMBERS>);
```

Comment: This is a generic issue. See [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html). Read the list that starts with *SELECT retrieves rows from zero or more tables. The general processing of SELECT is as follows:*.  Basically `WHERE` is processed before the output rows. You will need to repeat the `concat()` in the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like has been commented, you cannot refer to *output* column names in the `WHERE` clause. Only to *input* column names. You'd have to repeat the expression. See:

- [GROUP BY + CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537)

But there is more.

Strings are single-quoted: `'string'`. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

If your tables are not trivially small you'll want to improve performance with indexes. Your predicates have to be "sargable". For this, you have two basic options:

#### 1. Expression index

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON info_table ((area_code || '-' || phone_triad || '-' || phone_quad));

SELECT area_code || '-' || phone_triad || '-' || phone_quad AS phone_number
     , first_name, last_name
FROM   info_table
WHERE  area_code || '-' || phone_triad || '-' || phone_quad IN (<list OF numbers>);
```

Note the expression `area_code || '-' || phone_triad || '-' || phone_quad` instead of your original `concat()` expression. Why? See:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)
- [String concatenation using operator "||" or format() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555257/string-concatenation-using-operator-or-format-function/66556331#66556331)

#### 2. Split up input

And work with basic indexes on one or more parts of the number:

```sql
WITH nr AS (
   SELECT phone_number
        , split_part(phone_number, '-', 1) AS area_code
        , split_part(phone_number, '-', 2) AS phone_triad
        , split_part(phone_number, '-', 3) AS phone_quad
   FROM  (
      VALUES 
        ('123-456-789')  -- your input here
      , ('223-456-789')
      ) input(phone_number)
   )
SELECT nr.phone_number, i.first_name, i.last_name
FROM   nr
JOIN   info_table i USING (area_code, phone_triad, phone_quad);
```

See:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

To keep input numbers that are not found in the result, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. Then `null` values are filled in for `first_name` & `last_name` - which is distinguishable from actual column values if at least one of your columns is defined `NOT NULL`.

Either way, you have to handle `null` values, empty strings and leading and trailing white space properly.